# Archiving iOS Project with Framework Code

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am developing two iOS apps in Swift that have common code and resources, so I moved the shared parts to a Swift-only Framework.  The app projects and the Framework are grouped together in an Xcode Workspace.  Everything works fine when I build and run the apps in Xcode.

Problems arise, however, when I try to Archive an app, validate the Archive, and upload the Archive to iTunes Connect.  I have tried various combinations of embedding a binary, linking a Framework, and dragging the Framework into the app's projects.  I don't really understand what I am doing, so it's just groping in the dark.

Can somebody tell me the correct way to link/embed my Framework into my app for distribution?  I would like to know how to do this without a third-party dependency manager.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've countered such situation.
Did you use Framework project in your workspace?
If so, you have to add the framework in embedded binary in project's setting.
You can find it in first tab in setting.
When you test it in simulator, there is no error.
But if you want to build it for device or archive for uploading binary, you need to add it in embedded binary setting.
If you want I can help you to do it through teamviewer.